# Зачем делать импорт через нижнее подчёркивание?

Tags: python, библиотеки, python-import

```
import re as _re
import itertools as _itertools
import collections as _collections
from threading import Thread as _Thread, Lock as _Lock
import time as _time
```

Увидел такое в библиотеке keyboard

Comment: Мне субъективно кажется, что это бессмысслица, лишь усложняющая код непонятно зачем

Comment: Если вы внутри модуля `mod` (именно модуля) сделали `import math`, то `mod.math` стало частью интерфейса модуля. Вы обычно этого не хотите. Вам `math` был нужен для вычислений, а не чтобы он засорял ваш модуль. `import math as _math` вводит символ `mod._math`, который частью интерфейса модуля не является. Это только соглашение, но всё же оно работает. Авторы борятся против мусора в своих интерфейсах.

Comment: Изрядно напрягшись можно сделать чистый интерфейс другими средствами. Но там требуется определённая дисциплина и тесты. А импорты можно регулярным выражением проверить в момент комита кода в репозиторий.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это попытка победить подсказку IDE, которая во внешнем модуле не отличает родные имена в модуле и импортированные. Например, тот же пишарм радостно пихает в подсказку многочисленные объекты модуля typing из чужого модуля, да еще на первых местах. А так можно такое хоть вниз списка опустить.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В комментариях указали, что это не методы и я полностью согласен. Используются имена для модулей и пакетов с нижним подчеркиванием. Обратимся к [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) и зададимся вопросом, какого тут происходит?
И единственное, что я нашел, относительно данного вопроса, так это:

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.

> **Перевод:** Ведущее единичное подчеркивание - это слабый индикатор "внутреннего использования". Например, `from M import *`, такой импорт не будет импортировать объекты чьи имена начинаются на нижнее подчеркивание.

Других причин импортировать таким образом я не знаю. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

**UPD**

Я не ошибаюсь, вот [здесь можно почитать на английском](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-July/127286.html).

Вкратце. Имена с ведущим подчеркиванием классифицируются как «внутренняя реализация», и никаких будущих гарантий обратной совместимости не предполагается. То есть если вы будете использовать эти же самые модули в вашей реализации вы должны их импортировать отдельно и не использовать их из `keyboard` модуля. Модули должны быть импортированы явно.

После того как ответ был найден, решил сделать показательный пример того, зачем это применять.

Для примера были созданы два файла `t1.py` и `t2.py`. Их содержание

```py
# t1.py

from t2 import *
test_func()
print(math.sqrt(25))

# t2.py

import math
def test_func():
    print("Here is test function!")
```

Запускаем `t1.py` на исполнение и получаем:

```
Here is test function!
5.0
```

То есть из `t2.py` мы импортировали и модуль `math` и `test_func`, которые отрабатывают в штатном режиме.

Теперь изменим импорт `math as _math`:

```py
# t2.py
import math as _math
def test_func():
    print("Here is test function!")
```

И, в принципе, на этом этапе `VSCode` отрабатывает и показывает, что `math`-модуль в `t1.py` недоступен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но что будет, если я воспользуюсь именем `_math` с нижним подчеркиванием? Тут `VSCode` говорит, что все в порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при выполнении `t1.py` я получу следующее:

```
Here is test function!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\t1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(_math.sqrt(25))
NameError: name '_math' is not defined
```

Таким образом мы оградили модуль `math` только для использования в `t2.py`. *Только для внутреннего использования* в `t2.py`. И для того чтобы воспользоваться тем же самым модулем из `t1.py` мы должны импортировать его явно

```py
from t2 import *
import math
test_func()
print(math.sqrt(25))
```

Comment: Это не методы..

Comment: А, точно) просто как имя используется

Comment: Правило про подчёркивание и интерфейс модуля относится к любым символам, не только методам. Ответ правильный, его надо немного доработать и будет шоколадка.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы при импорте не затереть аналогично названный модуль. Например у вас есть описанная функция **func1** и вы импортируете **func1** из другого модуля, в таком случае вы затерёте импортированный модуль. Поэтому, чтобы такого не было - делается импорт через нижнее подчеркивание

Comment: Это называется "перекрыть", "перекрытие". "Затирание" как-то не очень звучит. )

Comment: @CrazyElf, зато понятно =))