# Импорт импортов из другого файла

Tags: python, python-import

Я увидел много схожих вопросов, но ни один, из которых я прочитал, не дал ответа

```
Директория be like:
-configs
--config.py
--config2.py
-__init__.py
-__main__.py
```

Есть главный файл **main**.py, в этой же папке есть 2 файла: **init**.py и папка configs
В папке configs 2 файла: config.py и config2.py, если в первом файле некоторые переменные, которые до этого нормально импортировались в **main**.py, то во второй я захотел засунуть все импорты в принципе, которые понадобятся в **main**.py. Написал простую функцию в config2.py:

```
def imports():
    global random, emoji, configs, config, TOKEN, KOKEN, ROBIN, ITD
    import random
    import emoji
    from configs.config import(
            TOKEN,
            KOKEN,
            ROBIN,
            ITD)
```

В **main**.py же в начале написал это:

```
from configs import config2
config2.imports()
```

В config2 все импорты работают, проверил дописав в конце:

```
imports()
print(random.random(), TOKEN)
```

Теперь сам вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы функция нормально работала внутри **main**.py, или какой есть вообще другой способ, который мне поможет?

Comment: Несколько раз прочитал - ничего не понял. Функция imports вообще что то странное. Зачем вообще импорт в функции?

Comment: А как реализовать по другому импорты в файл main? Нельзя же просто закинуть все импроты в config2 и потом его же импортировать в main. Насколько я помню, я так попробовал, ничего не получилось. А функция нужна, чтобы как раз когда её запускаем внутри main, то всё импортируется внутри него

Comment: Вам просто нужно понять суть. У каждого модуля есть свое пространство имен. Когда вы пишете `import` (в любом виде), то сначала исполняется импортируемый модуль сверху вниз. И в процессе выполнения заполняется пространство имен функциями, классами и т.д. И вот из этого пространства имен `import` перетаскивает нужное в пространство имен вашего модуля - и далее вы сможете обращаться  к этому по имени будто оно всегда было в вашем модуле. И поскольку это появилось в вашем пространстве имен - то уже из вашего модуля кто-то другой может импортировать это имя (хоть вы сами его себе импортировали)

Comment: Суть вроде как была и до этого понятна, а к чему всё это подводило?

Comment: Ну если бы я понял сам вопрос, то я бы ответил. А так как я не понимаю, то помог чем смог.

Comment: @vitidev понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374816/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?rq=1) нашел ответ, всё гораздо легче, чем я думал. Когда я пробовал просто импортировать файл (1)config2 путём `import configs.config2` в **main**, и внутри (1)него не было функции imports(), то все внутренние ссылки на модули внутри **main** должны были содержать перед этим 'config2.', до меня это почему-то не дошло. А если просто прописать `from configs.config2 import *`, то всё прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
import runpy
def include(file):
  globals().update(runpy.run_path(file,globals()))

include('../pip.py')
print(math.pi)
#3.141592653589793
```

суть в функции в том, что она исполняет указаный файл, так как будто его содержимое написано в основном. Ограничения: нельзя из файла а вызвать файл б в котором вызвается файл в. то есть в подключаемом файле данна функция не может быть исспользована

Comment: Я попробовал использовать этот код в main , но не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: @runk значит не верно исспользовал, внимательно перечитываем описание функции, затем создаём файл imports.py в котором импортируем всё(а не список того что нужно импортировать, то есть подключаемый файл должен быть валидным файлом питона), что нужно, затем майн пишем import('imports.py')

Comment: Во-первых, @ganz, мой ник - Rurik, а не runk. Во-вторых, ответ я уже нашёл, и он чуть ниже вашего. В-третьих, что значит "валидным файлом питона"? В-четвертых, это уже придирка, за оформлением текста следите пожалуйста, вы же в программе не пишете pprint или importss, как здесь "исспользовал", или несколько других ошибок в основном ответе, или выделить __main__.py, вместо "майн". Это не влияет на саму суть ответа, но повысило бы его быстроту понимания

Comment: во первых, что автоподсказка подсказала то и написал, во вторых не нужно было писать коммент, в третьих гуглите, товарищ, гуглите или вам ещё о табуляции рассказать? в четвёртых вы будете смеяться но pprint пишу и мало того это работает. и вот это уже придирка: прежде чем учить меня грамотности,- исправьте ошибки в своем комме: тире без запятой здесь уместно? запятые расставьте там где просите меня следить за оформлением, примеры в кавычки возьмите, ну что вы прямо как школодрон? - либо сами пишите грамотно либо не цепляйтесь к этому.